# How to print object value using key as another string

Tags: object, react-hooks

I'm trying to print an objects value by not its own key but a string similar to the key. I somehow got the key match using filter function from the useParams() string, just one more step remaining for my desired output.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function MoreArticle() {
  const feed = {
    Fall : 'This is the Detailed description about season of Fall',
    Summer : 'This is the Detailed description about season Summer',
    Winter : 'This is the Detailed description about season Winter',
    Monsoon : 'This is the Detailed description about season Monsoon',
    Spring : 'This is the Detailed description about season Spring',
  };

  const { name } = useParams(); //Summer
  const seasons = Object.keys(feed);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {seasons.filter(season => {
          console.log(feed.season);
          return(
            season == name && <div>{season}</div> //Returns Summer
            //season == name && <div>{feed.season}</div> 
            //How to return object description  
            //by using something like this value |
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MoreArticle;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `feed.season`, consider using the bracket notation to target a specific key value pair, like this: `feed[name]`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function MoreArticle() {
  const feed = {
    Fall : 'This is the Detailed description about season of Fall',
    Summer : 'This is the Detailed description about season Summer',
    Winter : 'This is the Detailed description about season Winter',
    Monsoon : 'This is the Detailed description about season Monsoon',
    Spring : 'This is the Detailed description about season Spring',
  };

  const { name } = useParams(); //Summer

  return (
    <div>{feed[name]}</div>
  );
}

export default MoreArticle;
```

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: The log statement below filter prints all 5 descriptions but the return statement for div only shows Summer on screen.

Comment: Yes, I know - I've updated my answer to have some example code

Comment: That helped, thanks alot! :)